# How to add ICollection object to Create View Model MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, create-view

My scenario is:
I have a class called "CarService" as below:

```
 public class CarService 
    {

        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public Car Car { get; set; }

        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public Person Service { get; set; }

        public DateTime ServiceEntryDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime ServiceExitDate { get; set; }
        public ICollection <CarServiceAction> CarServiceActions { get; set; }
    }
```

this class has a collection "`ICollection <CarServiceAction> CarServiceActions`"

the CarServiceActions is as below:

```
public class CarServiceAction
    {
        public int CarServiceId { get; set; }
        public CarService CarService { get; set; }
        public float Value { get; set; }

    }
```

the problem is when I create the controller  with views using Entity Framework it allows me to add all fields of CarService but there is no any data entry form for collection `ICollection <CarServiceAction> CarServiceActions`

This is my create view generated from controller:

```
@model RentaCar.Models.Instances.CarService 
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewData["Title"] = " ";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>CarService</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CarId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select asp-for="CarId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CarId"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ServiceId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select asp-for="ServiceId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ServiceId"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ServiceEntryDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="ServiceEntryDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ServiceEntryDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ServiceExitDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="ServiceExitDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ServiceExitDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is how can I add details of CarServiceAction by click an "adddetail" button.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `@model ICollection<RentaCar.Models.Instances.CarService> ` ?

Comment: This is create form for CarService which contain a list of CarServiceAction

Comment: Exactly what data do you need to be passed in from the controller?

Comment: For example: CarId = 1; ServiceId = 1; ServiceEntryDate = 12-12-2017; ServiceExitDate = 12-12-2018; CarServiceAction{{CarServiceId = 1; Value = 500},{CarServiceId = 1; Value = 700}}

Comment: Is that the _only_ thing you need from the controller?  If so then pass that in with `@model ICollection<RentaCar.Models.Instances.CarServiceAction>`.  If not then you'll either need to create a wrapper view model class which has that on it (preferred) or push it into the `ViewBag` (less preferred but it works).

Answer (score 0):

In fact I want to be something like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="CarService.CarServiceAction.CarServiceId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input asp-for="CarService.CarServiceAction.CarServiceId" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ServiceEntryDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input asp-for="CarService.CarServiceAction.Value" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="CarService.CarServiceAction.Value" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
<input   value="add new service action" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
```